# MAMP/Apache on OsX El Capitan does not find DocumentRoot when Port=80

Tags: macos, apache, mamp

I am having "weird" problems with MAMP (3.5.2)/Apache on Mac OS (El Capitan 10.11.5) when running it on Port 80.

Apache gets started and the WebStart page is displayed properly. However, it does not seem to find the DocumentRoot and when connecting to "localhost" it displays the Not Found message ("The requested URL / was not found on this server.").

If I change the port number to any other number X (I tried with 82, 8080, 8123 and of course 8888) then "localhost:X" correctly find the index.html of my DocumentRoot.

I checked with lsof if there is anything else interfering on the port but it does not seem to be the case. I also checked here on stackoverflow but did not find anyone with similar problems.

I am used to web programming but less familiar with web servers quirks.

I would be truly grateful for any clue on what's happening.

(It is not mandatory that I set the port to 80, although I would very much prefer to avoid having the port number in the URL. However, I just hate things I do not understand).

Answer (score -1):

I had the exact same problem and as I couldn't find any solution I created myself a workaround by adding a virtual host named `localhost` inside `MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

`<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "YOUR_ROOT_FOLDER"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>`